# R Psych package: extract factor number from fa.parallel function

Tags: r, statistics, psych, factor-analysis

I conducted a parallel analysis with the `Psych` package in R.
I want to extract the number of factors from the output of `fa.parallel()` function, and save it to a variable for further processing. I checked the [document](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/psychTools/vignettes/factor.pdf) but did not find how to do it.

My code is like:

```
fa.parallel(cor(data), n.obs=nrow(data), fa="fa", n.iter=100, main="Scree plots with parallel analysis")
```

Output is a scree plot with:

```
Parallel analysis suggests that the number of factors =  2  and the number of components =  NA
```

I want to extract "2" in this case. How should I achieve it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This document *[psych: Procedures for Psychological, Psychometric, and Personality Research](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/psych/psych.pdf)*(P160) lists the return values of `fa.parallel` function.
Among them, `nfact` is the number of factors with eigen values > eigen values of random data -- what we want.

So the code to extract number of factors suggested from `fa.parallel` function is like this:

```
parallel <- fa.parallel(cor(data), n.obs=nrow(data), fa="fa", n.iter=100, main="Scree plots with parallel analysis")
parallel$nfact #number of factors
```